# Batch Script to do operation on all subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a program that does something to a folder.  From the Command Prompt, I just need to type in the following to achieve what I need:

`program.exe C:\folder\subfolder1`

However, now I need to do this for multiple subfolders in `C:\folder`:

```
program.exe subfolder1
program.exe subfolder2
program.exe subfolder3
...
program.exe subfoldern
```

I wrote a batch script but it keeps adding `%i` to the end of my subfolder path.
This is what I have:
`for /r %%i in (%%i) do program.exe %%i`

The result is almost what I want, except the `%i` at the end of the path

```
program.exe subfolder1\%i
program.exe subfolder2\%i
program.exe subfolder3\%i
...
program.exe subfoldern\%i
```

How do I fix this so that the `\%i` is not in the path of my subfolder?

Comment: `FOR /D %%G IN (C:\folder\*) DO program.exe %%G`

Comment: The parameter needs to be quoted in case it has SPACE or other special characters. `FOR /D %%A IN ("C:\dir\*") DO (program.exe "%%~A")`

Comment: @Squashman your answer worked for me, but I can't accept it as an answer since it's a comment =)